# Can contributing to 401(k) make me eligible for Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira

In 2022, the Roth IRA contribution limit [reduces from $6000 to $0](https://www.schwab.com/ira/roth-ira/contribution-limits) for as income increases from $129k to $144k (for a single filer). The 401(k) limit is $20,500.

If my salary is $145k (too high for Roth IRA contributions), would contributing $20,500 to my workplace's 401(k) reduce my income to $124,500 for Roth IRA purposes, allowing me to contribute the full $6000?

Comment: In most cases, you can do a "backdoor Roth IRA contribution" (i.e. a non-deductible Traditional IRA contribution followed by a conversion to Roth IRA) if your income is too high for a direct Roth IRA contribution, and if you have no pre-tax money in Traditional/SIMPLE/SEP IRAs, the result of a "backdoor Roth IRA contribution" is exactly the same as a direct Roth IRA contribution.

Comment: @user102008 understood; the two scenarios I'm more concerned about are (1) pre-existing Traditional IRA balance makes backdoor impractical/undesired (rollover to 401(k) could alleviate this though, if the plan allows rollovers) and (2) large, late-year increases in income pushing above the limit *after* Roth IRA contributions have already been maximized (based on lower expected income)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. MAGI is reduced by 401(k) contributions, and contributing to a 401(k) can reduce your MAGI to the point where you are eligible for Roth contributions.

[Non-authoritative source](https://www.fool.com/retirement/plans/401k/contribute-to-401k-and-roth-ira/):

> If you're a higher-income earner on the edge of qualifying for a Roth IRA contribution, making a 401(k) contribution could push you under the income limitations, since those contributions don't count toward your AGI. That would open the door for more flexibility with short-term savings in a Roth IRA.

Comment: "MAGI is inclusive of 401(k) contributions" - Did you mean to say "exclusive"? "Inclusive" would mean that 401(k) contributions do not reduce MAGI.

Comment: @void_ptr Changed the wording to make it clearer. 401(k) contributions reduce your MAGI.